# Windows and Linux Beowulf cluster

Tags: windows, cluster-computing, opensuse

So here's my situation:

- I have a windows 10 PC
- I have a spare older openSUSE PC

I'm using the windows 10 PC with VSCode for some python machine learning.

I want to add the openSUSE PC's CPU and RAM capabilities to my current PC's capabilities to speed up the python code. It seems I want a Beowulf cluster. However, it doesn't seem that anyone has tried a Beowulf cluster with a windows and a linux pc together.

Can someone confirm whether this is possible and if so, point me in the right direction for research?

Thanks